# Protected mode fails if data segment is non-zero

Tags: assembly, operating-system, nasm, boot, bootloader

While working on a very simple bootloader I discovered that assigning something to the data segment (ds) before running into protected mode creates a processor fault.

This code works just fine:

```
[BITS 16]
[ORG 0x7c00]

xor ax,ax
mov ds,ax

cli
lgdt [gdt_descriptor]  

mov  eax, cr0       
or eax,1              
mov  cr0, eax

jmp CODE_SEG:now

[BITS 32]
now:
    jmp $

    db 0
gdt_start:
gdt_null:
    dd 0x0
    dd 0x0
gdt_cs:
    dw 0xFFFF ; Limit
    dw 0x0000 ; Base
    db 0x0000    ; Base 23:16
    db 10011011b
    db 11011111b
    db 0x0000
gdt_ds:
    dw 0xFFFF ; Limit
    dw 0x0000 ; Base
    db 0x0000    ; Base 23:16
    db 10010011b
    db 11011111b
    db 0x0000
gdt_end
gdt_descriptor:
    dw gdt_end - gdt_start - 1
    dd gdt_start

CODE_SEG equ gdt_cs - gdt_start
DATA_SEG equ gdt_ds - gdt_start

times 510-($-$$) db 0  ; fill sector w/ 0's
db 0x55          ; req'd by some BIOSes
db 0xAA
```

This one makes the processor restart:

```
[BITS 16]
[ORG 0x7c00]

mov ax,0x10 ;<-- Pre-assigning data segment
mov ds,ax

cli
lgdt [gdt_descriptor]  

mov  eax, cr0       
or eax,1              
mov  cr0, eax

jmp CODE_SEG:now

[BITS 32]
now:
    jmp $

    db 0
gdt_start:
gdt_null:
    dd 0x0
    dd 0x0
gdt_cs:
    dw 0xFFFF ; Limit
    dw 0x0000 ; Base
    db 0x0000    ; Base 23:16
    db 10011011b
    db 11011111b
    db 0x0000
gdt_ds:
    dw 0xFFFF ; Limit
    dw 0x0000 ; Base
    db 0x0000    ; Base 23:16
    db 10010011b
    db 11011111b
    db 0x0000
gdt_end
gdt_descriptor:
    dw gdt_end - gdt_start - 1
    dd gdt_start

CODE_SEG equ gdt_cs - gdt_start
DATA_SEG equ gdt_ds - gdt_start

times 510-($-$$) db 0  ; fill sector w/ 0's
db 0x55          ; req'd by some BIOSes
db 0xAA
```

I compiled this with NASM and I ran it with VMWARE.

Why does this happen?

Comment: You're loading `ds` with an incorrect value. Why would you expect it to work?

Comment: Where the documentation specifies that ds must be non-zero before the long jump that loads protected mode. Besides that, 0x10 is the correct value, after jumping in protected mode i can set ds to 0x10 and it works fine

Comment: @Felipe: Jonathon's answer below is correct; but only touches on the one specific problem you're having now. You have many other problems, including relying on false information ("ds must be non-zero before the jump"), not understanding the differences between real mode segment loads and protected mode segment loads, incorrectly assuming BIOS left certain registers in a certain state, etc. Even switching to protected mode in the first 512-bytes of a boot loader is a design mistake.

Comment: @Felipe:  Mostly, you need a more lengthy discussion to properly resolve all the issues; and the "specific answer for one specific problem" format that this site is designed for isn't really suitable for discussions like that. I'd suggest asking for comments on a forum intended for OS development (e.g. forum.osdev.org ).

Comment: The problems you talk about are only worries of as you said OS design, I'm not developing an OS, that code spinnet is just an effort to understand certain things, I wanted to understand why that specific problem happened and I achieved it by posting a question here, there are many sources with solutions to the specific "problems" you're talking about, but I'm not interested in going into that right now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't that you're setting `ds` before entering protected mode. The problem is that you're setting `ds` before executing the `lgdt` instruction.

The `lgdt` instruction also accesses memory in the data segment, so `ds` needs to be a correct value when you execute it. When you changed `ds`, you changed the effective address of the GDT you were trying to load. Then, when you went to enter protected mode with a `cs` segment in that GDT, the GDT entry was bogus, and the processor generated an exception. Finally, because you hadn't yet set up an IDT, the processor double-, then triple-faulted and rebooted.

Let's say `gdt_descriptor` is 0x40 bytes into your code, which means it's at `0000:7C40` when your bootloader is loaded.  When `ds` is zero (your first example) the `lgdt [gdt_descriptor]` instruction then would try to load a GDT from the base/limit at `(0x0 << 4) + 0x7C40 == 0x7C40`.  When you set `ds` to `0x10` however, you are now trying to load a GDT from the base/limit at `(0x10 << 4) + 0x7C40 == 0x7D40` which is not what you intended.

So you can set `ds` to `0x10` before entering protected mode - just don't do any memory accesses (i.e. `lgdt`) until after you've far jumped into PM.